# Ember log every click

Tags: logging, ember.js

I would like to log every click (whether that is through transitions, views, auto generations, ect ...) in some datastore for later analysis.

I realize this is probably a deal breaker for using ember as there are a lot of these activities that do not depend on a server side api call, so there will be no record on the server of a link clicked that transitions to another page.

However, that app I wish to analyze is already created in ember, thus my post.

I am aware of the following attributes that can be added to `Ember.Application`:

```
LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
```

They produce helpful information.  However, I do not know how to capture the output that it generates in the console and put it in variables for use later; possibly to send to a datastore each time a click happens, or perhaps to accumulate and then send based on some threshold.  I realize this may affect the performance of the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you interested in tracking clicks that don't transition to a new route? For example, a click that focuses the cursor on a form element or a click of an action button?

Comment: More so transitions.

Comment: At some point later, I may want to capture some info about the cursor on a form element or a click of an action button, ect ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [ember-metric](https://github.com/poteto/ember-metrics) and write a simple adapter for it so that it sends the data to your storage. Notice how it instructs you to extend the router, so that tracking is done automatically after every transition - you can do the same without using ember-metric.

Comment: I have not tested this, but this looks like what I was looking for.